# Using the Zend Framework should the file system be accessed via the controller or a model

Tags: php, zend-framework, filesystems

Should the server or network shares be accessed via the controller directly or some kind of model created?

I can use code like this in the controller:

```
$path = '/var/www/uploads';
$fileArray = array();
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
  if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
    $fileArray[] = array('filename' => $fileinfo->getFilename(), 'extension' => $fileinfo->getExtension(), 'size' => $this->bytesToSize($fileinfo->getSize(),2), 'modified' => date('d/m/Y H:i', $fileinfo->getMTime())); 
  }
}
$this->view->fileList = $fileArray;
```

This would mean repeating every time which seems the wrong way to do things in MVC.  Should I be creating a model that maps the file system, or does Zend have domething that can do this?

e.g. //PSEUDO CODE

```
$directory = new Zend_Directory();
$this->view->filelist = $directory->listFiles();
$directory->addFile('filepath');
$directory->deleteFile('filepath');
```

With similar sorts of functionality, upload, delete, rename, move, copy, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you're just going to pass this array to the view like in your example, make a view helper. If you want to just retrieve the same array and use in your controllers, make an action helper. If you need more functionality then you've presented here, make a model.

Comment: One of the major features that I was looking for, was the ability to save files to a specific file structure. 
e.g. when given an invoice, it should save in a folder with the path
/basepath/customer/invoice/file
This path would have to be made on the fly, and I was expecting to create a function somewhere that would turn the document type, i.e. invoice and the customer id into the path and then save the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it a model. That way you can do unit tests, easily swap out new controllers, and reuse the model in other projects.

A good rule of thumb is: If it directly interacts with data (a database, a service, a file, etc.), make it a model.

And there actually is a proposal for `Zend_Directory` and `Zend_File` ([link](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Directory+and+Zend_File+-+Steven+Brown)), but it doesn't look like any work has been done on it since 2009.

You might want to consider packaging your code as a plugin that others can use. Maybe use the link I posted above as a starting point.

Comment: Sounds like a model it is.  I will have a go and see if it is worth contributing once finished.  What would you include in a Zend Directory/File model as the link you gave me is pretty sparse?

Comment: Scroll down and there is a section called "Class Skeletons" that you can model it off of. Though, as one of the comments points out, this functionality already exists in SPL (DirectoryIterator: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php, general reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php). You might not want to make your own plugin because of this reason. Your Model should directly interact with SPL iterators and objects. However, you shouldn't use SPL objects in the Controller, since the actual data storage platform shouldn't matter in the Controller, just in the Model